# Can't query JSON (Laravel + VueJS)

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

my problem exactly smiliar with this one [cant't query json data in laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343614/cantt-query-json-data-in-laravel-5-2)

Already try to implement the right answer from it but still, no luck.
I don't know why....

Previous, i found this [Laravel 5.2 Codeception functional test issue with PUT / PATCH requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990335/laravel-5-2-codeception-functional-test-issue-with-put-patch-requests) too, already try to use suggestion from him, but no luck too.

Here's my Laravel Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $phonebook = Phonebook::findOrFail($id);
    $phonebook->update($request->all());

    // even i try this
    // Phonebook::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
    // return Response::json() or return response()->json();
    // No luck
}
```

My function in vue script for update data

```
editContact: function(id)
    {
        this.edit = true
        var contactid = this.newContact.ID

        this.$http.patch('/api/contact/' + contactid, this.newContact, function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
    },
```

Change my vue script to be like the right answer from question above, same result. No effect.

And my button to do edit like this

```
<form action="#" @submit.prevent="addNewContact">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contactName">Name : </label>
            <input type="text" v-model="newContact.CONTACTNAME" class="form-control" id="contactName">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number : </label>
            <input type="text" v-model="newContact.PHONENUMBER" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" v-if="!edit">Add new Contact</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" v-if="edit" @click="editContact(newContact.ID)">Edit Contact</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Note :
My route file using resource or manual route always same

```
Route::resource('/api/contact/', 'PhonebookController');
```

or

```
patch('/api/contact/{id}', ['uses' => 'PhoneboookController@update']);
```

And then, there something strange.
[image: Detail request]

(Maybe i am wrong) there no issue or error if we look the detail. But, if we change to response tab the result was empty
[image: No response!]

After all that process, nothing happen with the data.

CONTACTNAME should be "Mizukiaaaaaaaa" like first screenshot instead of "Mizuki"
[image]

Am I missing something??
Any advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing and ask so much people about this, finally found it! There's nothing wrong with the request or response. My mistakes are mutator update that i used and my model.

**Updated answer**

Reason answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306890/laravel-5-mutators-only-work-when-i-create-a-record-and-not-when-i-update-a-reco) and then I just changed update function on controller. Here the result

```
public function update(Phonebook $phonebook, Request $request, $id)
{
    // You can add any fields that you won't updated, usually primary key
    $input = $request->except(['ID']);

    // Update query
    $saveToDatabase = $phonebook->where('ID', '=', $id)->update($input);
    return $saveToDatabase;
}
```

My previous answer updated all fields including the primary key, somehow it successful update data, but it leave error for sure (duplicate primary key). The query looks like `UPDATE SET field = 'value'` without condition.

This case is for model that doesn't have any relation with other models (tables), or the model act as master.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested to you, try to invert the params in your `update` method in your controller.
And to get a response, you have to send it back (with code 200, 400, 401, whatever you want).

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $phonebook = Phonebook::findOrFail($id);
    $phonebook->update($request->all());

    // your treatment

    return Response::json([
       'param' => 'value'
    ], 200);

}
```

If you want to debug and see it in you response, you can make a `dd('debug')`in your method, you'll see it in the Ajax request response.

That should work for you !

Comment: yes i do, and the result? Same, data not updated :(
I think, maybe there something wrong with update() method or $request->all

`return Response::json($phonebook, 200);` this extract my updated values from the form, but those values isn't updated existing data

Comment: Put the code `dd($id);` on the top of your update method and tell me if you get your id in the response.  Logically, an exception should be thrown if you entity is not found, you should use a try / catch around your findOrFail method. Finally, check that your model has the correct fields specified intro the $fillable array.

Comment: got it bro! Yes, there's nothing wrong with the request and response, but the problem lies on mutators (i used) and model that I have!! After read [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306890/laravel-5-mutators-only-work-when-i-create-a-record-and-not-when-i-update-a-reco) and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679268/laravel-5-update-overwriting-all-data) , i try to implement it and then yes! It works. Thanks for all your help dude, apreciate it and sorry already bother you :)

Comment: Nice ! you should post an answer to explain what was wrong and the solution you found for those who encounter the same issue ;)